# If-else in C++ Programming Language

Tags: c++

I am a little bit confused about this code. Why does the else block get executed?

Please explain it.

```
int a=10,b=20;
char x=1,y=0;
if(a,b,x,y){
    cout << "A" << endl;
}else{
    cout << "B" << endl;      
}
```

Comment: My C++ is a bit old now, but this (a,b,x,y) doesn't make much sense here. It may only evaluate the last item y which is 0 and therefore falsy. What did you expect this to do?

Comment: (<flashy thing> Forget about the semicolons. I was confusing `if` with `for`.) You're abusing the comma operator, and it's yielding a true value.

Comment: Just because it compiles doesn't mean it makes sense. Also the compiler actually gives you a warning about this: `warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect`

Comment: @thorstenmuller if you are a beginner programmer then you code "for loop" to print 10 numbers which is also doesn't make any sense but its just for a practice. So I am practicing ..

Comment: Look, with "no sense" I just meant that the if works differently and part of this is ignored, and that it only compiles for some details of how C++ works (as basically npinti explains in his answer). Yep, you learned something important here (C++ can make a true/false value out of a lot of things). This is actually the source for many errors (like by accident assigning a value with x=0 instead of comparing x==0). You are totally right to try out such things, even if they look weird. But that is why I asked what you did expect it to do.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an implementation issue.

Comment: This should be on Stack Overflow.

Comment: -1 because it's off-topic and because you appear to be programming by wildly guessing, which is just never going to work, is it?

Comment: I'm ok with the wildly guessing bit.  Some people learn that way.  Just because they're guessing now doesn't mean they always will be.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) Wiki Page:

> In the C and C++ programming languages, the comma operator
>   (represented by the token ,) is a binary operator that evaluates its
>   first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second
>   operand and returns this value (and type).

So this: `if(a,b,x,y){` will only take the value of `y` into consideration for the actual `if` part, which has a value of `0` which would evaluate to `false`, thus causing the `else` part of your code to execute.

EDIT: That being said, the code you posted does not make much sense. The comma operator will evaluate and discard the result (other than the last item). This would be helpful if you would need to chain a series of methods which depend on each other and decide what to do by using the result of the last one.